# What is wrong with my procedure sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

my procedure is like below;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateWEEK_SALES_REPORTS

(   p_start IN WEEK_SALES_REPORT.StartDate%TYPE,
     p_end IN weekly_sales_report.EndDate%TYPE)

IS

BEGIN


 UPDATE WEEK_SALES_REPORT SET ComAmount = SaleAmount*ComRate WHERE (StartDate-EndDate) = (p_start-p_end);

 SELECT concat('The commission amount for report ',ReportID,' has been updated to ',ComAmount,' dollars,
 which is',ComRate,'% of the total sale amount of ',SaleAmount,' dollars.')

 COMMIT;


END;
```

/

but  show errors is

> 7/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> 7/10     PL/SQL: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Comment: Because you are running this in Oracle but you have this tagged with sql server. Which DBMS are you actually using??

Comment: i actually do sqlplus  first time for me to ask question, might get wrong tag

Comment: I believe Oracle concat will only take 2 params so you would need to nest them. But the double pipe `||` should do the same if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're trying to print your message to the console. For that, you want `dbms_output`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateWEEK_SALES_REPORTS
(   p_start IN date,
     p_end IN date)
IS

BEGIN

 UPDATE WEEK_SALES_REPORT SET ComAmount = SaleAmount*ComRate WHERE (StartDate-EndDate) = (p_start-p_end);

 dbms_output.put_line('The commission amount for report ' || ReportID || ' has been updated to ' || ComAmount || ' dollars,
 which is' || ComRate || '% of the total sale amount of ' || SaleAmount || ' dollars.');

 COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: 0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
2/16     PLS-00201: identifier 'WEEK_SALES_REPORT.STARTDATE' must be
         declared
iduno what the errors mean

Comment: Oh, sorry - I don't think you can declare procedure parameters as *relative types*, you have to use explicit types, like `date`. I edited my answer, see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, @Jacob H is right, `CONCAT` takes only 2 parameters. Use `||` instead, much uglier than your version, though:

```
SELECT 'The commission amount for report ' || ReportID ||
       ' has been updated to ' || ComAmount || ' dollars, which is' ||
        ComRate || '% of the total sale amount of ' || SaleAmount ||
       ' dollars.' ...
```

Furthermore, you need to `SELECT` it `INTO` some variable like, f.i.

```
SELECT ... INTO myvar FROM DUAL;
```